# Saving multiple dataframe in sheets and books based on the condition

Tags: pandas

I am able to save multiple dataframe in multiple excel sheets.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Cloud.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


frames = {'Image': df1, 'Objects': df2,  'Text': df3 , 'Labels': df4}

for sheet, frame in  frames.items():
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet)

writer.save()
```

Now I want to create multiple files based on the dataframes column. For example, I want to create 4 excel files:

df1

```
Category              URL          Obj
A               example.com       Chair
A               example2.com      table
B               example3.com      glass
B               example4.com      tv
```

So my all datframes have 7 categories and I want to create 7 files based the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
frames = {'Image': df1, 'Objects': df2,  'Text': df3 , 'Labels': df4}

for sheet, frame in  frames.items():
    for cat, g in frame.groupby('Category'):
        # if file does not exist
        if not os.path.isfile(f'{cat}.xlsx'):
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{cat}.xlsx')
        else: # else it exists
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{cat}.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl')

        g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet)
        writer.save()
```

Comment: it looks good but its generating only the file for the first category.

Comment: and its just saving only the last  data frame in 1 sheet in the excel file

Comment: I have provided the exemplary data and according to that there should be 2 files.. A.xlsx and B.xlsx/ Each file should have 4 sheets which will be all the 4 data frames.